# How do I declare device capabilities for this app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, requirements

I have created an iOS 5.1 or later application for the iPhone 4S that requires a magnetometer, an accelerometer and also uses the Core Location framework

Apple's documentation is a bit confusing when it comes to declaring the device's required capabilities (confused over array or dictionary choice, entering YES/NO values, etc.) and I want to make sure I've added everything correctly.

This is what the relevant section of my `info.plist` looks like now :

```
Required Device Capabilities      Array    (4 items)
          item 0                  String   magnetometer
          item 1                  String   accelerometer
          item 2                  String   location-services
          item 3                  String   armv7 // was already added by default
```

*(I have also added the name of the app and an appIcon in the appropriate fields)*

Is the above information correct or do I need to add something more or change something?

Furthermore, the application was created to run on the iPhone 4S. But do the above requirements also let it run on other iPhone versions that I should include, or is the iOS 5.1 restriction limiting my app to only run on the iPhone 4S?

Should I also include somewhere that it can run on some version of iPod Touch or will it not run on one?

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent there is to provide required capabilities and not specific hardware (iPhone 4, iPod  Touch, etc).  As long as a device implements the required capabilities and has the minimum OS version that you are targeting then it will be able to run your app.

Comment: That's all I needed to know EIJay, thank you very much! (so I guess the way I declared hardware capabilities is correct after all?)

Comment: Yep.  Those requirements along with the iOS version dictate the devices that can run your app.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions regarding [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427746/confusion-over-validation-and-ad-hoc-distribution-of-ios-app) I'm having as well? :)