# Confusion over Validation and Ad-Hoc Distribution of iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created my first iOS app for the iPhone, as part of my MSc project

I don't want to upload it to the App Store but rather convert it into a file that the examiners can use to check my app on their own devices.

Therefore I need to save my app for `Ad-Hoc deployment`

I created an archive of my Xcode project and then followed [these steps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010547-CH2-SW1) suggested by Apple

A `myProject.ipa` file was created on my Hard Drive. Is this enough ? 
Is this all I need to send the examiner so that they can install the app in their own iPhone?

**because,** 
I noticed there was also a button called `Validate` on top of the `Distribute` button (I only pressed that to create the `.ipa` file) in the Archive Organizer

So I went back to the **Archive Organizer**, chose my archive once again and clicked on `Validate` and I got :

> No Application Records were found
>
> Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they
>   can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

I went to my iTunes Connect account and it is obviously empty, i.e.  I haven't submitted any apps to the AppStore.But I want to validate my app nonetheless, before sending it to the examiner to see if it meets all requirements (even if it is now working fine on my own device - just to be sure).

So what does the above message mean? Do I necessarily have to sumbit my app to iTunes connect (i.e. the AppStore) in order for it to be validated?

And also, *should an app first be validated in order to run on other devices as part of an Ad-Hoc distribution?*

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is only for when you are submitting your app to the App Store.  The reason you are getting the "No Application Records were found" message is because for submitting to the App Store, you actually have to create an App Submission in iTunes Connect first and get all of the metadata entered.

XCode queries for that record so that it can associate the project you are building.

For Ad-Hoc distribution, you need to make sure that the examiners devices are added in the distribution profile that you used when creating the archive.  You can then just give them the .ipa and they can install via iTunes.

Comment: I see. I only created an iOS Team Provisioning profile when I created my Apple Developer account. Does that mean I also need to create a new Ad-Hoc provisioning profile an then create my archive?

Comment: You will need to create a distribution profile (not development) and specify as ad-hoc.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, but unfortunately I needed to find a better way to test my app on other devices [discussion continued here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428714/is-there-a-way-to-test-an-ios-app-on-a-device-that-is-not-submitted-for-ad-hoc)