# Is there a way to test an iOS app, on a device that is not submitted for Ad-Hoc distribution?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

Having created my first iOS app as part of my MSc project I now need to send it (together with my report) to the examiners (basically upload it to the website of the University (via Moodle)).

However, I cannot possibly know *who* the examiners will be and have *any* information about *their* iPhones

So I cannot submit my app for Ad-Hoc distribution since I don't know what devices to include!

Is there some other way around (other than locating the examiners and asking them for all the necessary details) ?

Or do I basically have to demonstrate the app myself on my own device (where it is currently installed since I have iOS Developer privileges myself) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a good grasp of the options here:

1. Use your own development device and demo in person or lend the device.
2. Collect their UDIDs for ad-hoc use (you can use TestFlight or HockeyApp to make this process easier for them and you).

(There is an "enterprise" certificate that will do mostly what you wish if you pay a fair bit more money and prove you're a business, so it's not really an option for this scenario)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll have a look at TestFlight

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I was not able to demo in person or acquire the device IDs of the people to whom I needed to demo it I used Quicktime screen capture to capture me demoing the device in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for TestFlight here. Basically the process is

- Get the email addresses for the testers
- send TF invites to them
- invitee responds, which provides their device id
- you add the device ids to your provisioning profile, build and upload the app to TF
- TF emails an installation link to your test users.

It's not a completely ideal solution, in that it still requires you to obtain some information about the examiners - but if your University is accepting an iOS app as an MSc project, I think you could reasonably argue that they need to meet you part way in the process.